# Can't install cocoapods on macOS Big Sur

Tags: ios, installation, cocoapods

I am using MacOS Big Sur 11.0 Beta.
I tried to install cocoapods but I can't.

First, I tried with;

```
sudo gem install cocoapods
```

It says

```
ERROR:  Error installing cocoapods:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.
```

Then, I tried with;

```
/bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install.sh)"
brew cleanup -d -v
brew install cocoapods --build-from-source (also tried with "brew install cocoapods")
```

It says

```
Error: pkg-config: no bottle available!
You can try to install from source with:
brew install --build-from-source pkg-config
```

So, I tried `brew install --build-from-source pkg-config`, and it says `Error: macOS '10.16' is invalid`.

Anybody can help me?